# Name lookup rules for nested-name-specifier

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, qualified-name

I've read the following (3.4.3/1):

> If a :: scope resolution operator in a nested-name-specifier is not
>   preceded by a decltype-specifier, **lookup of the name preceding that ::**
>   considers only namespaces, types, and templates whose specializations
>   are types.

What is the lookup rule for nested-name-specifier?

For example:

```
#include <iostrem>

namespace A
{
    int j=5;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << A::j //I assume that A will be searched as just *unqualified-name* appeared inside the function which is a member of namespace
}
```

The second example:

```
namespace A
{
    namespace B
    {
        int j=5;
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << A::B::j
}
```

Is it true that in the second example A::B will be looking as qualified name inside the namespace? I.e. we can define rules for **nested-name-specifier** lookup inductively. But I cant find anything like that in the standard. Is it true at all?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3199139/nested-namespaces-in-c

Comment: @ldgorman There is no answer to my question.

Comment: Interesting.  In terms of the formal grammar, the `A` in `A::j` is not actually an _unqualified-id_....

Comment: @aschepler So what A does mean?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's inductive, and I'd say it simply follows from the wording. First, let's add full parenthesizing based on the associativity of `::`:

```
(std::cout) << ((A::B)::j)
```

<sup>(The above is just to demonstrate how the parser understands precedence, it's not valid code).</sup>

So `j` is qualified by the name `A::B`. It's a qualified name, so it's looked up according to 3.4.3.

`A::B` is itself a qualified name (it conforms to the syntactic form outlined by 5.1.1/8), so it is looked up according to rules for a qualified name.

Comment: To be clear, `(A::B)::j` is not valid code; the parentheses just represent the way the parsing works.