# Can one namespace be a member of another namespace?

Tags: c++, namespaces

Well the question is straightforward, can I declare a namespace inside of another namespace? If so, what is the correct term for this namespace, would it be called an 'inner namespace' or a 'nested namespace', or perhaps something different altogether?

Comment: Look at this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3199139/nested-namespaces-in-c

Comment: @icemanind No, the OP asks solely for nesting namespaces, not how to place objects into them (though I've been answering that also).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *"can I declare a namespace inside of another namespace?"*

Yes, you can nest namespaces as much as you want

```
namespace A {
    struct thingA;
    void funcA();
    namespace B {
        struct thingC;
        void funcB();
        namespace C {
            struct thingC;
            void funcC();
        }
    }
}
```

And refer to the above declarations using the `::` (scope) operator:

```
A::thingA thingA;
A::funcA();

A::B::thingB thingB;
A::B::funcB();

A::B::C::thingC thingC;
A::B::C::funcC();
```

> *"what is the correct term for this namespace, would it be called an 'inner namespace' or a 'nested namespace', or perhaps something different altogether?"*

And also yes, it's usually called a *'nested namespace'*.

Comment: I'll up-vote this as soon as I stop being as lazy as the OP ;)

Comment: @DracoM. Well, looking at things like `std::chrono` it should become obvious.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious Well, with raising rep, I have the feeling to get lazier, which questions to answer ;) ...

Comment: Haha @πάντα ῥεῖ, at least someone is willing to answer my lazy day questions!