# Accessing a global variables within nested namespaces

Tags: c++, namespaces

I am quite new to c++ and having trouble with namespaces.

```
#include <iostream>

int x = 10;

namespace ns {
    int x = 5;

    namespace ns_nested {
        int z = x;  //z is assigned a value of 5??
    }
}


int main(){
    std::cout << ns::ns_nested::z;
}
```

This prints `5`. Initially, I thought this was because I was just changing the value of x to `5` from `10`.

But if I change the first declaration of x to `const int x = 10`, it still prints `5`.

So, my question here is twofold:

1. I though the variables declared in a global scope was... well... global, as in just one instance of it was available to all. So, why/how am I able to declare an instance of a variable with the same name again?
2. If I were to assign the value of `z` to the value of `x` that was declared globally instead of the one in the outer namespace, how would I do it?

Comment: In `int z = x;` `x` is being searched down the namespace hierarcy: first `::ns::ns_nested::x`, then `::ns::x` and then `::x`, `::ns::x` and `::x` are not the same.

Comment: One of the reasons to use namsespaces is so that different things can have the same name. I can make my own `sort` function and it will not collide with the standard sort since they are name `std::sort` and `my::sort`. Here you have `::x` and `ns::x`.

Comment: @Mubin - _So, why/how am I able to declare an instance of a variable with the same name again?_ - Would you wonder the same for `int x = 10; void fn() { int x = 5; }`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nested NameSpaces in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3199139/nested-namespaces-in-c)

Comment: Answer to 2:

`namespace ns_nested {
  int z = ::x;  
} //z is assigned a value of 10`

Comment: @Armali yes, actually.

Comment: @user3365922 and mcabreb thanks. that explans the answer to my second question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1) I though the variables declared in a global scope was... well... global, as in just one instance of it was available to all. So, why/how am I able to declare an instance of a variable with the same name again?

```
  namespace ns {
    int x = 5;

    namespace ns_nested {
        int z = x;  //z is assigned a value of 5??
    }
 }
```

here x is not global namespace it is under namespace ns

> 2)If I were to assign the value of z to the value of x that was declared globally instead of the one in the outer namespace, how would I do it?

see this you may got an idea

```
#include <iostream>

const int x = 10;

namespace ns
{
    int x = 5;

    namespace ns_nested
    {
        int z1 = ::x;    //global namespace
        int z2 = ns::x;  //ns namespace
    }
}


int main()
{
    std::cout << ns::ns_nested::z1<<std::endl;
    std::cout << ns::ns_nested::z2<<std::endl;
}
```